# Как подключить Android-планшет к OS X, чтобы он появился в списке устройств Android Studio?

Tags: macos, android-studio, android

У меня хакинтош. Обычный ноутбук с установленной на него OS X. Теперь я осваиваю разработку под Android и установил версию под OS X. Я хочу, чтобы при подключении устройства в списке устройств, на которых можно запускать приложение, появлялся планшет. Как этого добиться? В Windows для этого надо было установить драйвера из adt bundle. Как под Mac OS X все настроить?

Comment: Спросите на форуме про хакинтоши. На Mac OS все отлично видится(именно хакинтош). На Mac OS устройства видятся в ADB поумолчанию. Вы, видимо, что-то не так установили (может кекст на USB?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На Mac OS все отлично видится (именно хакинтош). На Mac OS устройства видятся в ADB по умолчанию.